# Arrow in jQuery validation engine

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-shapes, jquery-validation-engine

In JQuery validation engine for the promptPositions bottomRight and bottomLeft the arrow points towards top and vice versa. for centerRight Position I want to point the arrow towards the left side, and for centerLeft I want to point the arrow towards the right.

I worked on it. But, couldn't find  a better solution.

```
arrow.addClass("formErrorArrowBottom").html('<div class="line5"><!-- --></div>\n\
<div class="line6"><!-- --></div>\n\
<div class="line7"><!-- --></div>\n\
<div class="line8"><!-- --></div>\n\
<div class="line9"><!-- --></div>\n\
<div class="line6"><!-- --></div>\n\
<div class="line7"><!-- --></div>\n\
<div class="line8"><!-- --></div>\n\
<div class="line9"><!-- --></div>\n\
<div class="line10"><!-- --></div>');
```

I edited this in jquery.ValidateEngine.js. But vain. Do anyone know the correct format to get the arrow on the right and left.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Well I had the same problem, so I updated the CSS with:

```
.formError .formErrorArrow .sideline12 {
    width: 1px;
    height: 15px;
    border: none;
    float: left;
}

.formError .formErrorArrow .sideline11 {
    width: 1px;
    height: 13px;
    border: none;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 1px;
}

.formError .formErrorArrow .sideline10 {
    width: 1px;
    height: 11px;
    border: none;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 2px;
    border-top: solid 4px #fff;
    border-bottom: solid 4px #fff;
}

.formError .formErrorArrow .sideline9 {
    width: 1px;
    height: 9px;
    border: none;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 3px;
    border-top: solid 4px #fff;
    border-bottom: solid 4px #fff;
}

.formError .formErrorArrow .sideline8 {
    width: 1px;
    height: 7px;
    border: none;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 4px;
    border-top: solid 4px #fff;
    border-bottom: solid 4px #fff;
}

.formError .formErrorArrow .sideline6 {
    width: 1px;
    height: 5px;
    border: none;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 5px;
    border-top: solid 4px #fff;
    border-bottom: solid 4px #fff;
}

.formError .formErrorArrow .sideline6 {
    width: 1px;
    height: 3px;
    border: none;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 6px;
    border-top: solid 4px #fff;
    border-bottom: solid 4px #fff;
}

.formError .formErrorArrow .sideline5 {
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    border: none;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 7px;
    border-top: solid 4px #fff;
    border-bottom: solid 4px #fff;
}

.formError .formErrorArrow .sideline4 {
    width: 1px;
    height: 7px;
    border: none;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 8px;
    background: #fff;
}

.formError .formErrorArrow .sideline3 {
    width: 1px;
    height: 5px;
    border: none;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 9px;
    background: #fff;
}

.formError .formErrorArrow .sideline2 {
    width: 1px;
    height: 3px;
    border: none;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background: #fff;
}

.formError .formErrorArrow .sideline1 {
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    border: none;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 11px;
    background: #fff;
}

.formError .formErrorArrow .rightSideArrow {
    width: 14px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    z-index: 5;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

And ths JS with:

```
case "centerRight":
    prompt.find(".formErrorContent").before(arrow);
    arrow.addClass("formErrorArrowRight").html('<div class="rightSideArrow"><div class="sideline1"><!-- --></div><div class="sideline2"><!-- --></div><div class="sideline3"><!-- --></div><div class="sideline4"><!-- --></div><div class="sideline5"><!-- --></div><div class="sideline6"><!-- --></div><div class="sideline7"><!-- --></div><div class="sideline8"><!-- --></div><div class="sideline9"><!-- --></div><div class="sideline10"><!-- --></div><div class="sideline11"><!-- --></div><div class="sideline12"><!-- --></div></div>');
break;
```

And HTML:

```
<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery("#formID").validationEngine({ promptPosition: "centerRight" });
        });
</script>
```